# Get version of Service in WMI

Tags: windows-services, wmi-query

I installed a windows service using InstallShields generated msi file.

How am I able to get the version of the service using WMI-Query? I already checked win32_Service but there's no version number displayed. Is this information queryable using WMI or do I have to use the registry for this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, got it. The information is stored in Win32_Product.